# How to turn on advisement mode of BLE device by peripheral device (like android phone)?

Tags: android, ios, bluetooth-lowenergy

Generally we need to first turn on BLE advertisement mode by pressing a button, then a android or iOS phone is able to search for the BLE device . Otherwise BLE device goes on sleep mode, it needs a trigger to wake-up and other mobile is not able to search for it.
Is it possible to wake up a BLE device when there is a nearby peripheral device (android phone ) searching it ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes would be possible to wake-up a peripheral using a sort of scan-request / scan-response protocol, but would not be very useful for the power consumption.

What you need to consider is that if scan-request are enabled in a peripheral device, the device has to keep the radio in RX mode all the time to be able to receive the scan request packet. This has to be done even if there is no device out there that will actually send one (because the peripheral doesn’t know who is really out there). This means more energy consumed.

What can be done is a device that constantly advertises packets without going to sleep mode (and this is a very common way). With an advertisement interval of some seconds (e.g. 8 sec) there exist devices powered with small batteries that last for months / years.
The advertisment in this case should have a packet data unit of type ADV_IND (and not ADV_NONCONN_IND), since ADV_IND it’s connectable.
When a peripheral device sends an ADV_IND advertisements, it is helping Central devices such as Smartphones find it. Once found, a Central device can begin the connection process with the peripheral.

You can find useful info about BLE advertising [here](http://www.argenox.com/bluetooth-low-energy-ble-v4-0-development/library/a-ble-advertising-primer/).